# Any way to incorporate an f-string in an identifier?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, f-string

Lets say I want to produce a number of variables, but the actual amount I am unaware of (as may depend on the input, etc.), the only thing differentiating the variables from one another is a piece of information in their identifier. Is there any way that this is possible in Python 3?

Coded example (using f-strings):

```
for i in range(3):
  f'variable{i}' = i

print (variable0)
print (variable1)
print (variable2)
```

Meaning the output of this program would be:

```
0
1
2
```

Comment: The best way to handle this would be to use a list:  `variable = list(range(3))`.  Then you can use `variable[i]` to access the individual elements.

Comment: Sounds like a XY question. Can you elaborate on why you need multiple variables instead of e.g. a dict?

Comment: @TomKarzes yeah, I think I will probably use lists as they fit the best in my case. Thanks!

Comment: I've seen this question come up numerous times, and it always confuses me.  How can you use a variable if you don't know ahead of time if it will exist?